# Where do I put my php files to have Xampp parse them?

Tags: xampp

I finished installing Ubuntu 10 for netbooks, and XAMPP. The XAMPP website tutorial made it very easy to install, then left me high and dry. Everything works, but I have no idea where to put my handwritten php files.

After a few hours of googling, and trying to understand the file explorer, I realized I have no idea where anything is in ubuntu. For an answer, please don't just tell me "go to "X" directory. I won't know how to navigate there.

I also did a file search for htdocs with no luck.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in XAMPP the default root is "htdocs" inside the XAMPP folder, if you followed the instructions on the xampp homepage it would be "/opt/lampp/htdocs"

Answer (score 18):

I created my project folder 'phpproj' in

**...\xampp\htdocs**

ex:...\xampp\htdocs\phpproj

and it worked for me. I am using Win 7 & and using xampp-win32-1.8.1

I added a php file with the following code

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

was able to access the file using the following URL

```
http://localhost/phpproj/copy.php
```

Make sure you **restart your Apache server** using the control panel before accessing it using the above URL

Answer (score 2):

When in a window, go to GO ---> ENTER LOCATION...
And then copy paste this: /opt/lampp/htdocs

Now you are at the htdocs folder.
Then you can add your files there, or in a  new folder inside this one (for example "myproyects" folder and inside it your files... and then from a navigator you access it by writting:
localhost/myproyects/nameofthefile.php

What I did to find it easily everytime, was right click on "myproyects" folder and "Make link..."... then I moved this link I created to the Desktop and then I didn't have to go anymore to the htdocs, but just enter the folder I created in my Desktop.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `httpd.conf` and/or `httpd-vhosts.conf` files and search for the `DocumentRoot` entry. If you configure multiple virtual hosts, there may be more than one of those, separated in `<VirtualHost>` tags.

Comment: I don't know what the httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf files are and I don't know where they are. Typing them into my browser bar didn't work. I don't know where files and folders are in ubuntu and this is the kind of help i need. For an answer, please don't tell me to "look at file x." I need help navigating to the correct file.

Comment: `/path_to_your_apache_install/conf/httpd.conf` a file search *will* turn them up.

Comment: If there is any such Apache install folder it is hidden from me. I have no idea how to find it.

Comment: `CDeanMartin` try `locate httpd.conf` or if that is not available, `find / -name "httpd.conf"` (the latter will throw a lot of "access denied"s, that's okay)

Comment: But this is starting to belong on superuser.com :) voting to migrate there.

Comment: locate httpd.conf didn't work. find / -name threw about 50 permission denied errors but did nothing else

I suspect the problem is related to running Ubuntu on a pendrive. I used 1 GB for persistence. Does this affect where I would find the XAMPP installation files?

Comment: @CDeanMartin I don't know, I've never used Ubuntu on a USB Drive, nor XAMPP on a Linux... Maybe ask again on superuser.com or serverfault.com, summarizing the current situation?

Answer (score -1):

This will work for me:

```
.../xampp/htdocs/php/test.phtml
```

Comment: But, make sure you have to add respected files to this location: go to xampp folder, open htdocs and then create a new folder called php. otherwise, it won't recognize the system.

Answer (score -2):

The default location to put all the web projects in `ubuntu` with `LAMPP` is :

```
 /var/www/
```

You may make symbolic link to public_html directory from this directory.[Refered.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1820085) Hope this is helpful.